# Error: expecting a string in R

Tags: r, string

I am running the following code:

```
 mydataframe <- mydataframe %>% 
   mutate(newVar1 = abs(as.numeric(CanBe1 == 0 & lead(var_id, default = 0) == (var_id + 1)) - 1)) %>% 
   group_by(pt, item) %>% 
   mutate(newVar2 = abs(as.numeric((CanBe2 == 0 & lag(var_id, default = 0) == (var_id - 1)) ) -1),
          newVar2 = ifelse(lag(newVar1, default = 0) == 1, 1, newVar2))
```

but I get an error: `Error:expecting a string`. What does it mean? where exactly there should be a string?

Here are few examples of the data I have, and I expect:

```
 pt     item   var_id    CanBe1    CanBe2    newVar1    newVar2
 1      9      2         0         0         0          1
 1      9      3         0         0         0          0
 1      9      4         1         0         0          0
 1      9      5         0         0         1          0
 1      9      7         0         0         0          1
 1      9      8         1         0         1          0
 1      9      10        0         1         0          1
 1      9      11        0         0         0          0
 1      9      12        1         0         1          0
 1      9      2         1         0         0          1
```

The variables I am using are:

```
 class(mydataframe$pt) = `factor` #even if I change this one to `character` the code doesn't work
 class(mydataframe$item) = `character`
 class(mydataframe$var_id) = `character`
 class(mydataframe$CanBe1) = `numeric`
 class(mydataframe$canBe2) = `numeric`
```

Comment: You need to set `mydataframe$var_id` to numeric. `var_id + 1` and `var_id - 1` doesn't make sense to R because it considers the variable to be a string character.

Comment: @Phil even if I have other variables in `mydataframe` that need to stay as characters?

Comment: Yes, just wrap `var_id` with `as.numeric()`.

Comment: @Phil, if you post your comments as an answer, I will accept it, as it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var_id` is currently a character string. Reclassifying it as numeric ahead of time will fix it.

```
 mydataframe <- mydataframe %>% 
   mutate(var_id = as.numeric(var_id), #Switching from character to numeric
     newVar1 = abs(as.numeric(CanBe1 == 0 & lead(var_id, default = 0) == (var_id + 1)) - 1)) %>% 
   group_by(pt, item) %>% 
   mutate(newVar2 = abs(as.numeric((CanBe2 == 0 & lag(var_id, default = 0) == (var_id - 1)) ) -1),
      newVar2 = ifelse(lag(newVar1, default = 0) == 1, 1, newVar2))
```